# Application of Stirling's theorem for the given series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to prove whether $x=-4/27$ is convergent or not for the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{3n}{2n}x^n$$

I applied alternating series test. But, while using this, I need to apply Stirling's theorem so as to show that $a_n(4/27)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Please can someone do this? I tried but I cannot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stirling's approximation says

$$k! \sim \sqrt{2\pi k} \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k.$$

Inserting that into $\binom{3n}{2n}$ yields

$$\binom{3n}{2n} \sim \frac{\sqrt{6\pi n} 3^{3n} n^{3n} e^{-3n}}{\sqrt{4\pi n}2^{2n}n^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{2\pi n}n^ne^{-n}} = \frac{\sqrt{6\pi n}}{\sqrt{4\pi n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}\left(\frac{27}{4}\right)^n = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(\frac{27}{4}\right)^n,$$

so

$$\binom{3n}{2n}\left(\frac{4}{27}\right)^n \sim \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{\pi n}} \to 0.$$